# How can I search the bash history and rerun a command?

Tags: unix, bash

Can I search history in bash and run the result?

Answer (score 561, accepted):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at the command line and start typing the previous command.  Once a result appears keep hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> to see other matches.  When the command you want appears, simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note that while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> is the default, if you wanted the command (`reverse-search-history`) to be bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> you could configure that with the following:

```
bind '"\C-t": reverse-search-history'
```

There are a whole host of other readline bindable commands that are available to you as well.  Take a look at the [`bash` man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands).

Bash has many facilities to search and access interactive command history.  The most basic of which is the `history` builtin.  Typing just:

```
$ history
```

Will print a list of commands along with a numeric index, like:

```
$ history
1 clear
2 ls -al
3 vim ~/somefile.txt
4 history
$
```

You can then execute any of these commands using their numeric index by prefacing the index with a single `!`, as [Mitch](https://superuser.com/users/2681/mitch) pointed out:

```
$ !1
```

Will execute the `clear` command.  The history builtin has many features itself, you can see more in the `bash` and `history` man pages.

You can also specify relative negative offsets when using the `!` designator, so using our history list above, if we wanted to execute `vim` again, we could do:

```
$ !-2
```

Which is basically telling bash to execute the command you ran "two commands ago."  To run the previous command in the history list, we can just use `!!` (which is just shorthand for `!-1`).

The `!` designator doesn't limit you to numerically specifying which command to run. [hayalci](https://superuser.com/users/770/hayalci) showed that you can instruct `bash` to execute a command based on either the text it begins with (using `!`) or text within the command itself (using `!?`).  Again, using our example history list above, if we wanted to execute `clear` again, all we need to do is type:

```
$ !cl
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  And what about `vim`?  That is as simple as:

```
$ !?some
```

The most important point from [hayalci](https://superuser.com/users/770/hayalci)'s response is the call to the `shopt` builtin:

```
$ shopt -s histverify
```

This will enable history verification so that commands that are matched by the `!`, `!!`, and `!?` designators are not blindly executed, but instead filled in on the command line so you can ensure they will do no evil before executing them.  This is even more important when you are executing commands as the root user.  This option can be set in your `.bashrc` startup file so that it is set whenever you log in.

As has already been pointed out, all of this information can be gleaned from the [`bash` man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).  For the !, !!, and !? designators, take a look at Section [9.3 History Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).

Comment: +1 I have been Using Linux for over 12 years for all systems. I didn't know that existed. Wish I could +10 *how did I miss it??*

Comment: On many systems, pressing the up-arrow does the same.

Comment: If somebody were to consolidate '!', '!!', '!?', 'history | grep', and 'ctrl-r' into a comprehensive answer, I would select it

Comment: `shopt` goes in bashrc, not bash_profile (or it won't be enabled for shells that aren't login shells).

Comment: Also after pressing CTRL+R you can use CTRL+SHIFT+R multiple times to jump back to the previous command

Comment: You can also run `!!` to run the previously command. For example `sudo !!` to run the previous command with sudo.

Answer (score 60):

You could also do:

```
history | grep "stuff"
```

it would return something like

```
num stuff
```

then you can type

```
!num
```

Comment: Explanation for `!num` 
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Event-Designators

Answer (score 39):

As an alternative to <kbd>crtl+R</kbd>, you can search history by typing

```
!text
```

This will search the history for the most recent command *beginning* with 'text'.

But I suggest you put this in your .bashrc to prevent execution of wrong command.

```
shopt -s histverify
```

This instructs bash such that, after **any** history actions (like `!!:s/prev_text/after_text`), it places the resulting line to the command prompt. Then you can review or edit the command, and press Enter afterwards.

Comment: Use !?text to re-execute the most recent command containing (as opposed to beginning with) "text".

Comment: If somebody were to consolidate '!', '!!', '!?', 'history | grep', and 'ctrl-r' into a comprehensive answer, I would select it.

Answer (score 22):

I prefer to use history-search-backward over reverse-search-history. The former lets you type a few characters of the command *then* press the search key, as opposed to hitting the search key first then typing the search string.

By default on my system, M-p and M-n bind to similar functions but I prefer binding the arrow keys:

```
bind '"\e[A":history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B":history-search-forward'
```

Answer (score 14):

I have a really great alias, h. It's really just "history | grep", but I filter out previous "h command" entries with the "grep -E -v"

```
alias h="history | grep -E -v '^ *[0-9]+ *h ' | grep "
```

used like

```
h aliases
2003  less .bash_aliases
```

Comment: This can also be accomplished by adding the command to `HISTIGNORE`.

Answer (score 13):

Excellent writeup, Sean!  I'd put this in a comment, but I'm a few reputation points shy.  :-)

Another related and useful technique is the ability to run a previous command while changing a word.  Say you typoed the directory name, or want to change the file name:

```
$ echo my name is bob
my name is bob
$ ^bob^jordan
echo my name is jordan
my name is jordan
```

Notice that the command is expanded, replaced, and output before the command is run, so if the wrong command is run you can see what bash thought it was doing.

Answer (score 8):

As navigation through history using Ctrl-r is IMO cumbersome, you may want to consider **hh**:

https://github.com/dvorka/hstr

which makes navigation much simpler, straightforward and efficient - including running the command:

[image]

Comment: How to use it? Which keys to press to see this picture?

Comment: Once you install hh you can either use hh command OR bind it to any keyboard shortcut (typically Ctrl-r) as described in the documentation.

Comment: it binds to `ctrl + r` by default now

Comment: Reason to use hh: "As navigation through history using Ctrl-r is IMO cumbersome", How to use it: "Bind it to Ctrl-r" :- o

Answer (score 4):

At the bash command prompt, type control-R, then type a few characters of the command you want and bash's readline facility will search through the command history for that command.

After you have started the search, you can type control-R again to jump to the next matching command.

Answer (score 3):

If you have your shell configured to use `vi` key bindings (`set -o vi` or having `set editing-mode vi` in `$HOME/.inputrc`), then you search with `<Esc>/some-command<Return>` and hit `n` (next) or `Shift-n` (previous) to cycle through the command line history.

Comment: This one is the closest to vim users.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> works just fine, like @John1024 suggested, but is somewhat tedious if many of your recent commands are similar and you want a quick way to scan them all. An alternative would be to use [`history`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html):

```
$ history | grep keyword
```

Answer (score 2):

I like HSTR, but I can't seem to be able to install it sometimes.
So I wrote an alias using [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) which mimics its behavior (`hx`, for "history execute")

```
alias hx='eval $(history | sed "s/^ *[0-9]* *//g" | fzf --tac --tiebreak=index --height=10)'
```

- `history` : well, get the history
- `sed` : remove the index column from the list (POSIX)
- `fzf` : here is the magic, allows you to fuzzy-search the list interactively, move with `C-J` and `C-K`, and pick a command with `Enter`.
- `--height` : set the numbers of lines shown.
- `--tac` : revert list (more logical for a history)
- `--tiebreak=index` : keep the history order when fzf updates the results

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this is still not mentioned yet. You can set it in your per-user inputrc file like that:

```bash
nano ~/.inputrc
```

```
# Respect default shortcuts.
$include /etc/inputrc

# Use Shift+Up/Down to search history
"\e[1;2A": history-search-backward
"\e[1;2B": history-search-forward
```

Super easy, clean, per-user and flexible. Works without any major permissions and will be auto-applied on login.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Or use `"\e[1;3A"` and `"\e[1;3B"` for Alt+Up/Down

Answer (score 0):

```
# USAGE: find.history cd
# filter commands in shell history by a search term and execute the selected command
function find.history {
  eval $(history | grep "$1" | tail | awk '{$1=""}1' | tail -r | peco)
}
```

You will need to have `peco` installed.

https://github.com/peco/peco

`[$]> brew install peco`